# node set up and install

Tags: node.js, file

from my understanding I need to create a file called server.js and then paste this code in it

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Where do I put this file? 
I know where the node_modules folder is but I am not sure where to sit this server.js file.

Comment: Just open terminal and run `node server.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the server file anywhere that you want. Once you've done that, open Command Prompt or Terminal and enter this command:

```
cd C:\the\full\path\to\the\file\server.js
```

but, of course, enter the correct path to the `server.js`. After that, you should enter the command:

```
node server.js
```

And the server will start!

Comment: Just a side note: You mentioned the node_modules folder. If you have any dependencies (normally declared in your packages.json) you can easily add them via **npm install** from your command line.